# End of communication tcp server nodejs

Tags: node.js, tcp

Knowing that TCP is a stream based protocol, in the following example of a client server in nodejs what is telling the server that the client has finished sending all data?

Server

```
var net = require('net');

var server = net.createServer(function(socket) {

    var remoteAddress = socket.remoteAddress + ':' + socket.remotePort;
  console.log('new client connected: %s', remoteAddress);

    socket.write('Echo server');
    socket.pipe(socket);
});

server.listen(1337, '127.0.0.1');
```

client

```
var client = new net.Socket();
client.connect(1337, '127.0.0.1', function() {
    console.log('Connected');

    for ( var i=0 ; i<100; i++) {
      //  console.log(i);
       client.write('Hello, server! Love, Client.\r\n');
    }

});

client.on('data', function(data) {
    console.log('Received: ' + data);
    client.destroy(); // kill client after server's response
});

client.on('close', function() {
    console.log('Connection closed');
});
```

Thanks

Comment: #client.end() ? https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_socket_end_data_encoding

Comment: I am not explicitly calling and end right? the loop keeps writing my data. is there an implicit end attached when my write function ends?

Comment: i haven't experienced a lot with the net module, but I don't think there is. You should explicitly end the communication, at least on the client's part. with the end() method